# How to pre populate current password while changing password through devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, spree-auth-devise

Hello I have given following view file

```
<div class="panel-body">
      <%= form_for @user, :url =>update_change_password_user_path(spree_current_user.id), :method => :put do |f| %>
        <p>
          <%= f.password_field :current_password, class: "form-control"%>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= f.label :password, Spree.t(:new_password) %><br />
          <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "form-control" %><br />
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= f.label :password_confirmation, Spree.t(:confirm_password) %><br />
          <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => "form-control" %><br />
        </p>

        <%= f.submit Spree.t(:update), :class => 'btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

My requirement is to get current_password field pre filled please guide me hot to fetch current_password of user. I am using `gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.0.0'`

Comment: How do you want it to be prefilled?

Comment: in the old password field it must be present in non readable formate show that the user has to provide new and confirm new password in the form and then submit. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: if they don't need to fill it out don't put it on the form

Comment: It is not possible,  password saved in encrypted format so we can not get correct password from ruby, I think you some how can fill password by js if password saved in coockies

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need a placeholder - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp, so it would be: